# Passing data using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsdictionary

I've been researching this and trying options for the last 2 days and am stumped.  I have a page where a user can swipe a cell and sees the following options
[image]

When the user clicks Report User they should be taken to a page with a form that allows them to submit a complaint about another user.  The first VC is called Messages and it should pass the username of both the reporting user and the one being reported.  Right now only the reporting user is being passed as it's in a NSDictionary. The latest method I've tried is causing the app to crash with a 'libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException'  Here is a sample of the code:

```
 let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Report User" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:IndexPath!) -> Void in


        let shareMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Report User", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let editBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Harrassment, Inappropriate Content, Abuse", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            self.reportPost(indexPath)

        }
        //let harrassAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Harrassment", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

        shareMenu.addAction(editBtn)

        shareMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
       self.present(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })

func reportPost(_ indexPath : IndexPath) {
        let guest = self.guest[indexPath.row]
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ReportVC", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReportView") as! ReportViewController
        vc.reportLbl.text = guest as? String
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a variable instead and pass the data to this variable. Something like: `var guest: String?` inside of your `ReportViewController`. And pass your data: `vc.guest = self.guest[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Let me try that now

Comment: still crashing with libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException error

Comment: Are you tried an answer? As mentioned below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ReportVC storyboard (strange name for a storyboard but ok..), select your ReportView scene (in InterfaceBuilder) and verify in the Identity Inspector that its Storyboard ID is set to "ReportView".  Also make sure the class is set to ReportViewController.

It should look like this:

[image]

**Update:**

After chatting with techgirl, it turned out the storyboard wasn't named "ReportVC" after all.  So for those reading this answer, please also check that you're referencing the correct storyboard file.

Comment: thank you for responding. Unfortunately it's still crashing with a libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

Comment: Also make sure the "Inherit Module from Target" is checked... at least I think it should be.  The one in the screenshot above isn't checked because I don't actually have a class named ReportViewController in my project.

Comment: Also, which line is crashing?  I've been assuming it was the one where you called: storyboard.instantiateViewController

Comment: I'm getting a Thread 1 Signal SIGABART error in the AppDelegate file line 'class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {'

Comment: Ok so put a breakpoint on the instantiateViewController line.  Do you reach the breakpoint?  If so, step over it...  Does it crash?  If not, keep stepping to see at which line the problem happens.  Maybe the reportLbl isn't wired up as an outlet, in your storyboard.  Or it could actually be _any_ controls or views missing an outlet in that storyboard scene you're loading.

Comment: I'm able to reach the breakpoint.  After stepping over it I evenly get a 'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)' on the AppDelegate page.